# how to give a link with functions on the href atribute in html

Tags: javascript, html, function, tags

I am creating a following link in my web site

```
<a class="newimg forimgs " href="javascript:activateTab('newpost');javascript:mymodelII(newpostmesg);javascript:slidethecontent(contentinthetopicnewpost)" > New </a>
```

so when the user click on this link it changes the tab. How to change the link to something like this while the functions are still in the href attributes

> file:///C:/Users/pavithra/Desktop/mysites/adminhome.html?newpost

Answer (score 1):

You can use onClick() function of  tag for functions execution and href for its link.

```
<a class="newimg forimgs " href = "file:///C:/Users/pavithra/Desktop/mysites/adminhome.html?newpost" onclick="javascript:activateTab('newpost');javascript:mymodelII(newpostmesg);javascript:slidethecontent(contentinthetopicnewpost)" > New </a>
```

Comment: well this does what i wanted but when i reload the page it will again go to the main tab not the tab what i wanted

Comment: u can write jQuery.onReady() function and activate/redirect "new post" tab if "newpost" parameter is present in the url.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separated function for the hyperlink href, on its container.

```
<div class="hyperlink-container">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Go(){
      (function(){
        activateTab('newpost');
        mymodelII(newpostmesg);
        slidethecontent(contentinthetopicnewpost)
      })();
    } // this function will not affect another function because
      // it's applied to one container (div), on its top
    </script>
    <a class="newimg forimgs" href="javascript:Go()">
        New
    </a>
</div>
```

You could use the `onclick`/`onmouseover` attributes or properties to call these functions also.